# App crash logs not generated in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, nszombie, nszombieenabled

My app is behaving in a similar way has NSZombie enabled.it is crashing but crash logs are not generated. I have cross checked many times Nszombie is not enabled.So pls let me know how to fix this issue. To be more exact app gets hanged / frozen instead of quitting the application.

Comment: You haven't provided a question here. From what I can tell, you have said that your app is not crashing and is not producing crash logs (because it is not crashing). What's the problem?

Comment: @ian MacDonald the app is crashing but crash logs are not generated.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the kind of crash your are experiencing? Also, I find this statement from your question to be misleading: "it is not crashing".

Comment: NSRangeException ,sigabrt just for example. This problem happens for all exceptions. I have edited my question